# Django: allow line break from textarea input

Tags: html, django

How do I allow line breaking in textarea input in django to later show this input on page?

Comment: {{value|striptags|urlize|autolinebreaks} I do

Answer (score 99, accepted):

[linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks)

Replaces line breaks in plain text with appropriate HTML; a single newline becomes an HTML line break (`<br />`) and a new line followed by a blank line becomes a paragraph break (`</p>`).

For example:

```
{{ value|linebreaks }}
```

If value is `Joel\nis a slug`, the output will be `<p>Joel<br />is a slug</p>.`

Comment: When answering with a link, please also put the relevant information provided by it into your post in case the site goes down in the future

Comment: For those like me looking for jinja2 solution, the following stackoverflow link answers that. I had a tough time finding this answer so putting the link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436458/allowing-br-tags-with-google-app-engine-and-jinja2

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the `\n` characters for things other than rendering html, for example emails, or input values, or javascript?

Comment: Note: For models, the field should be `TextField`, not `CharField`.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `{% autoescape off %}` ! Otherwise user controlled input may not get escaped, which is a security risk. As mentioned use [linebreaks or linebreaksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks).

Answer (score 0):

I had a text area for user minimal custom input in the template and I wanted to keep whatever formatted text the user inserted to stay the same.
The solution, I simply changed the Model variable to a TextField type. It even shows the user formatted text in the admin. :)

ex.

```
class Uadds(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 1000)
```

title will not show line breaks, however, description will show them.
I haven’t tested this with a Rich Text Editor...
Hope this helped.

Answer (score -2):

Use `{% autoescape off %} {{ your_variable }} {% endautoescape %}`.

Comment: You should not do this it opens you up to a number of potential security problems. Use accepted answer.