# newline in models.TextField() not rendered in template

Tags: django, newline

I have a model with an attribute,

```
desc = models.TextField()
```

I entered data using admin interface provided by Django and then later viewed my template where the database values are fetched and displayed.

In my admin interface I left newline (just by leaving blank lines in between my paragraphs) but they are displayed as a single paragraph in my template.

I'm using Django 1.3 and MySQL.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[`linebreaks`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks)

> Replaces line breaks in plain text with appropriate HTML; a single newline becomes an HTML line break (`<br />`) and a new line followed by a blank line becomes a paragraph break (`</p>`).
>
> For example:
>
> `{{ value|linebreaks }}`

Comment: This works for rendering, but what if you want to keep the `\n` for javascript, input values, or emails?

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for the same, I have a model with text field and also corresponding admin class, I have no clue where to put this ??? do we need to override the html and create a template for it???

Comment: @Mike forgot to put his beak into this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894945

Comment: Such a simple solution! Works for DetailView too.

Answer (score 6):

Just a note, I was having a similar problem with newlines not showing up and I realized that when a TextField is declared as readonly, the text is wrapped with HTML paragraph tags:

```
<p> text </p>
```

as opposed to pre tags:

```
<pre> text </pre>
```

Pre tags preserve new line spaces, so if you do NOT make the field readonly, you will see the linespaces.

Answer (score 5):

John, looks like you got a great answer from Ignacio.  I just wanted to point out the steps that I took to use Ignacio's answer for those who may be confused (like I was).  Inside my template where I display the text field I added the "**|linebreaks**" behind the template field name (in my case a "job.desc"):

```
<ul>
    {% for job in varDataObject %}
    <li>
        <h4>
            <a href="#" onclick='funPath("Job", {{ job.id }})'>{{ job.title }} </a>
        </h4>
        Description: {{ job.desc|linebreaks }}
```

Comment: This answer could probably be a comment on Ignacio's answer

Comment: Thanks caulitomaz!  How do I repair the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Saving text with newline (not `\n`) in your model's TextField() using sql:

```
update event
set description='xyz
                asdasd
                 oaisjd '
where id=1;
```

In Django template:

```
{{ object.description|linebreaks }}
```