# Allowing <br> tags with Google App Engine and Jinja2

Tags: python, escaping, whitespace, jinja2, webapp2

In my web app, the user can make blog posts. When I display the blog post, newlines aren't shown because I didn't replace the new lines with `<br>` tags. The problem is that I've turned autoescaping on in Jinja, so `<br>` tags are escaped. I don't want to temporarily disable autoescaping, I want to specifically allow `<br>` tags. How would I do this?

Comment: You can use a `textarea` if you want newlines to be respected.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have another answer that I think is the best. Initially I was just displaying my variable `post.content` as-is, and the newlines weren't being preserved. None of the solutions here worked (well), and my pre solution was just a quick fix and had major issues. This is the real solution:

```
{% for line in post.content.splitlines() %}
    {{line}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `|safe` filter, or use the [autoescape](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#controlling-autoescaping) blocks:

```
{% autoescape false %}
{{ content goes here }}
{% autoescape %}
```

You could also set autoescaping in the [environment](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Environment) to `False`.

Comment: But what if it's not safe?

Comment: @LtWorf is right. You should assume user entered content to be malicious. Most of it won't be, but you don't want that one evil guy inserting JavaScript that gives your users viruses. -1

Answer (score 2):

In your model object, add a function like this:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    # ...

    def html_content(self):
        # Escape, then convert newlines to br tags, then wrap with Markup object
        # so that the <br> tags don't get escaped.
        def escape(s):
            # unicode() forces the conversion to happen immediately,
            # instead of at substitution time (else <br> would get escaped too)
            return unicode(jinja2.escape(s))
        return jinja2.Markup(escape(self.content).replace('\n', '<br>'))
```

Then in your template, just call that:

```
<p>{{ post.html_content() }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jinja2 filter:

```
import re
from jinja2 import evalcontextfilter, Markup, escape

_paragraph_re = re.compile(r'(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2,}')

@evalcontextfilter
def nl2br(eval_ctx, value):
    result = u'\n\n'.join(u'<p>%s</p>' % p.replace('\n', '<br>\n')
                          for p in _paragraph_re.split(escape(value)))
    if eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)
    return result
```

You need to add the filter to your jinja2 Environment before you can use it:

```
JINJA2_ENV.filters['nl2br'] = jinja2_filters.nl2br
```

In your template you can use that filter:

```
{{post.content|nl2br}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a filter wrote by myself:

```
import jinja2

@jinja2.evalcontextfilter
def nl2br(eval_ctx, value):
    result = jinja2.escape(value).unescape().replace('\n', '<br>')
    if eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = jinja2.Markup(result)
    return result
```

And add the filter to the `jinja2.Environment()` by calling:

```
jinja_env.filters['nl2br'] = nl2br
```

Comment: Note that this is unsafe as it passes HTML content. Should be: result = escape(value).replace("\n", Markup("<br/>"))

Answer (score 0):

Note that i have autoescape on by default, so I don't check it in this function, but this is what I'm using

```
def nl2br(value): 
  split = value.split('\n')
  return jinja2.Markup('<br>').join(split)
```

then of course,

```
jinja_env.filters['nl2br'] = nl2br
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to put `<pre></pre>` tags around the area where I had the content.

Comment: That's not a great solution - pre has implications on other things, like line wrapping.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is to escape the field yourself, then add line breaks. When you pass it in in jinja, mark it as safe so it's not autoescaped.