# Reading a text file into a 3d array

Tags: java, file, multidimensional-array

I want to read my content of a text file into a multidimensional array. My text file consists of strings in a specific format.

I just want to store it into a multidimensional array. I tried using java code to store into string or string array but I don't know how to store this format into a multidimensional array. Can any one help me?

my text file **read.txt** consists of

```
    { { "Kim","is" "playing" },         { "NOUN", "VERB", "DET" } },
    { { "Shine","is" "eating"},         { "NOUN","DET" "VERB" } },
    { { "Kevin","lives","in","Holland"},  { "NOUN", "VERB ","DET","Holland"} }
```

what I tried is :

```
    public class MyClass
    {
      static final String[][][] MULTI_ARRAY = new String[][][];
      public static void main(String args[]
      {
        for (String[][] myarray : MULTI_ARRAY) 

            String[] sentences = myarray[0];
            String[] partsofspeech = myarray[1];  
        }
      }}

      BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("read.txt"));
      while(br.ready)
      {
         MULTI_ARRAY[][][]=br.readLine();

      }
   }
```

**ie  I want  my 3d array in the below format**

```
    static final String[][][] MULTI_ARRAY = new String[][][] {
   { { "Kim","is" "playing" },         { "NOUN", "VERB", "DET" } },
    { { "Shine","is" "eating"},         { "NOUN","DET" "VERB" } },
    { { "Kevin","lives","in","Holland"},  { "NOUN", "VERB ","DET","Holland"} }
  };
```

Comment: Did you compiled this code?

Comment: @Mena I don't think that as a good option because if I consider JSON then it should be in the  format {"title":"jhdjashlashflfhlkdf"} but my data should not be considered as in JSON format

Comment: i Know it shows compilation error I don't know how to read it into an array

Comment: It depends on how you want to place this string in 3D array. Read line by line and split the line and put it in the array as you want

Comment: I want to place this array in the same format as it is in the text file

Comment: Do You want to set up a format, so It will be easily parsed in Java, or do You want to parse the exact format You have given?

Comment: A really crazy idea would be to put in `.java` source code as static field, then compile it and load it with `ClassLoader`. However this would require the user to heve JDK installed and it is ***horribly*** unsafe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume than the format is 1 2D block per line. Also I used `ArrayList`s instead of arrays, since you don't know the needed sizes in advance. Here is my code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));

List<List<List<String>>> d3 = new ArrayList<>();

while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();

    String[] splitted = line.split("(?<!\\\\)\\\"");
    List<List<String>> d2 = new ArrayList<>();
    d3.add(d2);

    List<String> d1 = new ArrayList<>();
    d2.add(d1);

    // ignore first and last
    for (int i = 1; i < splitted.length - 1; i++) {
        if ((i & 1) != 0) { // odd, add to list
            // unescape double quote and backslash
            d1.add(splitted[i].replace("\\\"", "\"").replace("\\\\", "\\"));
        } else { // even test if new array starts
            if (splitted[i].matches(".*\\{.*")) {
                d1 = new ArrayList<>();
                d2.add(d1);
            }
        }
    }
}

scan.close();
System.out.println(d3);
```

The idea is based on splitting the line by the `"` characted, however, you still can have quotes inside your strings if you escape them (`\"`) and thanks to [negative lookbefore](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) it will split correctly. But it will **fail** if there is backslash at the end of the string.

**EDIT:**

To convert from `List<List<List<String>>>` to `String[][][]` you can use this code:

```
String[][][] result = new String[d3.size()][][];
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = new String[d3.get(i).size()][];
    for (int j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
        result[i][j] = new String[d3.get(i).get(j).size()];
        for (int k = 0; k < result[i][j].length; k++) {
            result[i][j][k] = d3.get(i).get(j).get(k);
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result)); //see if result is ok
```

Comment: kajacx thank u for your reply but I want it in 3 d array format. how can I convert this

Comment: System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result)); and System.out.println(d3); yields same output List<List<List<String>>>

Comment: If by *"same output"* you mean same data, then yes, that was the whole idea.

Answer (score 1):

See also this answer: [Rendering newlines in user-submitted content (Python web app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356172/rendering-newlines-in-user-submitted-content-python-web-app/11356299#11356299)

I'd think of it as a state machine

```
[Start]
 |                                       
 v                                       
[Base-State]--{--->[2D-State]---{---->[1D-State]
|         ^         |     ^               |
|         |-----}----     |  read everything until next } into buffer,
EOF                       |  split by ',' into list, 
|                         |  append to multidimensional array
V                         |               |
[End]                     |----------------
```

Here's how you can build a simple state machine in pseudo code:

```
state = "Base-State"
buff = ""
parser: while(true) {
   currChar = readchar()
   switch case(state) {
      case "Base-State":
         if (currChar == '{') {
            state = "2D-State"
         }
         else if (currChar == null) {
            break parser
         }
         break
      case "2D-State":
         if (currChar == '{') {
            state = "1D-State"
         }
         else if (currChar == '}') {
            state = "Base-State"
         }
         else if (currChar == null) {
            //throw error
         }
         break
      case "1D-State":
         if (currChar == '{') {
            //throw error
         }
         else if (currChar == null) {
            //throw error
         }
         else if (currChar == '}') {
            //split buffer into list, put into array at fitting place
            state = "2D-State"
         }
         else {
            buffer += currChar
         }
         break
   }
}
```

So - every state corresponds to a case in the switch, every transition consists of an if-statement with a state assignment, every character in the transition represents the conditional in the if-statement.

Comment: MIchael I think it's really difficult to implement this

Comment: Please describe what's difficult. Putting it into words will help you understand better and maybe I can help you with your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to parse your Textfile.
I found this tutorial for parsing but u can parse your textfile as well.

[parser tutorial](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=525)

That what you tryed is not like it works. You have to understand that Your code gone be complied. But the textfile part is loaded after compiling and the text the bufferedreader reads would not be complied and the complied program can't read it.