# Print a python output to an html file

Tags: html, python-3.x

I am writing a script to print the output to an html file. I am stuck on the format of my output. Below is my code:

```
def printTohtml(Alist):
    myfile = open('zip_files.html', 'w')
    html =  """<html>
    <head></head>
    <body><p></p>{htmlText}</body>
    </html>"""

    title = "Study - User - zip file -  Last date modified"
    myfile.write(html.format(htmlText = title))
    for newL in Alist:
        for j in newL:
            if j == newL[-1]:
                myfile.write(html.format(htmlText=j))
            else:
                message = j + ', '
                myfile.write(html.format(htmlText = message))
    myfile.close()

Alist =  [['123', 'user1', 'New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip', '05-24-17'],
['123', 'user2', 'Iam.zip', '05-19-17'], ['abcd', 'Letsee.zip', '05-22-17'],
['Here', 'whichTwo.zip', '06-01-17']]

printTohtml(Alist)
```

I want my output to be like this:

```
Study - User - zip file -  Last date modified
123, user1, New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip, 05-24-17
123, user2, Iam.zip, 05-19-17
abcd, Letsee.zip, 05-22-17
Here, whichTwo.zip, 06-01-17
```

But my code is giving me everything on its own line. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance for your help!

My Output:

```
Study - User - zip file - Last date modified 

123, 

user1, 

New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip, 

05-24-17 

123, 

user2, 

Iam.zip, 

05-19-17 

abcd, 

Letsee.zip, 

05-22-17 

Here, 

whichTwo.zip, 

06-01-17
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
for newL in Alist:
        for j in newL:
            if j == newL[-1]:
                myfile.write(html.format(htmlText=j))
            else:
                message = message + ', ' + j
        myfile.write(html.format(htmlText = message))
```

For each element in newL, you need to store them in 'message'. Once each newL is completely read, write the 'message' into the myfile.

Comment: It just gave me the same thing.

Comment: try using break and \n together. br is needed in web page display and \n is needed in source display. \n basically means new line in the source display.

Comment: btw, are you using the aforementioned code instead of message = j + ', ' ?

Comment: I think my question is how do I remove that new line \n. For example in python 3, print(j + ', ', end = '') would remove the new line that way when we are printing elements of a list, they can all be on one line. My question is, how do I do the same thing if I want my output on an HTML file?

Comment: are you asking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11374198/4190159 ? If yes, then you can always use the replace method to do so. You can replace the \n with break. is that what you want primarilly?

Comment: Not quite what I want. This is how I want my output:  Study - User - zip file -  Last date modified
123, user1, New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip, 05-24-17
123, user2, Iam.zip, 05-19-17
abcd, Letsee.zip, 05-22-17
Here, whichTwo.zip, 06-01-17. Not everything on a  new line.

Comment: can you attach a link to a screenshot of your output instead for ease of understanding?

Comment: I edited my question with the output that I am getting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With each iteration, your loop is creating new `<head></head><body><p></p></body></html><html>`.

Also, if you want to remove space between paragraphs, use `<style>p { margin: 0, !important; } </style>`.

You could try this function which gives the `HTML` output you wanted.

```
def printTohtml(Alist, htmlfile):    
    html =  "<html>\n<head></head>\n<style>p { margin: 0 !important; }</style>\n<body>\n"

    title = "Study - User - zip file -  Last date modified"
    html += '\n<p>' + title + '</p>\n'

    for line in Alist:
        para = '<p>' + ', '.join(line) + '</p>\n'
        html += para

    with open(htmlfile, 'w') as f:
        f.write(html + "\n</body>\n</html>")

Alist =  [['123', 'user1', 'New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip', '05-24-17'],
['123', 'user2', 'Iam.zip', '05-19-17'], ['abcd', 'Letsee.zip', '05-22-17'],
['Here', 'whichTwo.zip', '06-01-17']]

printTohtml(Alist, 'zip_files.html')
```

The markup written to `zip_files.html` is:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<style>p { margin: 0 !important; }</style>
<body>

<p>Study - User - zip file -  Last date modified</p>
<p>123, user1, New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip, 05-24-17</p>
<p>123, user2, Iam.zip, 05-19-17</p>
<p>abcd, Letsee.zip, 05-22-17</p>
<p>Here, whichTwo.zip, 06-01-17</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The page displays the following output:

```
Study - User - zip file - Last date modified    
123, user1, New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip, 05-24-17    
123, user2, Iam.zip, 05-19-17    
abcd, Letsee.zip, 05-22-17    
Here, whichTwo.zip, 06-01-17
```