# Django TextField

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I want to display text that I entered without changing.

For example,

```
-I
-am
-entering
-a
-text
```

but when I display it is like

-I -am -entering -a -text

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: allow line break from textarea input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894930/django-allow-line-break-from-textarea-input)

Comment: or you could use something like http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: I prefer any other solution like changing a simple character like - with enter.

Comment: replace that char on save with a `<br />` then, did you try anything but the default behaviour so far?

Comment: Think that someone who don't know html will enter text so character have to be simple like -.

Comment: They can input a `-` which you will replace on your form save method with a `<br>`. Which is exactly what I said before. Btw: check the first comment. Seriously, do it.